# Building a set of tile coordinates

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have an image which I want to divide into tiles of specific size (and cropping tiles that don't fit).

The output of this operation should be a list of coordinates in tuples `[(x, y, width, height),...]`. For example, dividing a 50x50 image in tiles of size 20 would give: `[(0,0,20,20),(20,0,20,20),(40,0,10,20),(0,20,20,20),(20,20,20,20),(40,20,10,20),...]` etc.

Given a `height`, `width` and `tile_size`, it seems like I should be able to do this in a single list comprehension, but I can't wrap my head around it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what did you try? In your example, how can you divide 50x50 into 20x20 tiles. It would make 6.25 tiles. Are you ok with that?

Comment: This:
'`[(x,y,w,h) for x in range(width)[::tile_size] for y in range(height)[::tile_size] for w in [tile_size]*(width/w_tiles) + [w_padding] for h in [tile_size]*(height/h_tiles) + [h_padding]]`

Where the number of tiles per dimension (_tiles) and padding had been previously computed

Comment: @be_good_do_good if tiles don't fit, I have to use up as much as I can (in the example given, some tiles would be of size 10x20 or 10x10)

Answer (score 0):

Got it with:

```
output = [(x,y,w,h) for x,w in zip(range(width)[::tile_size],[tile_size]*(w_tiles-1) + [w_padding]) for y,h in zip(range(height)[::tile_size],[tile_size]*(h_tiles-1) + [h_padding])]
```

Comment: what is w_tiles? what is w_padding?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def tiles(h, w, ts):
    # here is the one list comprehension for list of tuples
    return [tuple(list(ele) + [ts if w-ele[0] > 20 else w-ele[0], ts if h-ele[1] > 20 else h-ele[1]]) for ele in itertools.product(*[filter(lambda x: x % ts == 0, range(w)), filter(lambda x: x % ts == 0, range(h))])]

print tiles(50, 50, 20)
```

[(0, 0, 20, 20), (0, 20, 20, 20), (0, 40, 20, 10), (20, 0, 20, 20), (20, 20, 20, 20), (20, 40, 20, 1
0), (40, 0, 10, 20), (40, 20, 10, 20), (40, 40, 10, 10)]